# Deploy runnable jar on local server

Tags: java, html, jar, applet

I have a runnable jar, which contains multiple classes within a package. I am trying to have this applet run on my local apache server using html.

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<p>Something</p>
</head>
<applet code="LoginGUI.class" archive="html.jar" width="640" height="480">
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

The program runs properly in Eclipse, but it does not load when called through the above html code. I think this may be due to the classes being within the package1 folder in the jar file, but am unsure how to rectify this, if this is indeed the problem. I have tested calling single classes through html, so this is not the issue as they work fine. Please advise on how this can be fixed, or if there is a more logical approach to this that I am unaware of. First time trying to do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all classes are in the `package1` package, then you should have:

```
<applet code="package1.LoginGUI.class" archive="html.jar" width="640" height="480">
</applet>
```